# Configuring Jenkins python specifically

Tags: python, jenkins

I’m trying to run a python script via execute shell script in `Jenkins`. 
From my understanding `Jenkins` is using its own shell or `Python` interpreter which is different from the local environment.

I.e , running the command `python -V` from Jenkins executing shell I’m getting `2.7.12 version`

In terminal running `python -V` I’m getting `3.7.0`
Which I aliased “python” in bash_aliases to `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

I’d like to be able to run in a specific Jenkins project the python that I’m using locally.

All of what I’ve tried is trash so it is not worth to share this garbage...

What is the right way to be able to run the python I want without changing Jenkins configurations.

Comment: Are you allowed to install [Shining Panda](https://plugins.jenkins.io/shiningpanda) plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Some more ways to get this working:

1. Instead of calling `python` from Jenkins, call `python3` to get the v3 interpreter.
2. In Jenkins, use the full path to the executable you are using locally:  `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`.
3. Create and source a [python virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/) at the very beginning of your job:

   ```
   python3 -m virtualenv local
   source ./local/bin/activate
   pip install --upgrade --requirement requirements.txt
   python ....
   ```

   (note that after you source the virtualenv, all calls to python and pip will automatically use the executables in `./local/bin` or where ever you create the virtualenv)

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an older post, I'm tossing in my answer since I landed here after some Googling.

I was having the same issue and found this to be my solve:
1st some info on my setup:

- Ubuntu
- A few versions of python in my /usr/bin/ folder
- I wanted to paste my python code directly into the build step

My solution:

1. Installed ShiningPanda plugin
2. Configured it using the info in https://plugins.jenkins.io/shiningpanda/

   *one note, you can name it whatever you want, just make sure the path is right (and I was able to ignore the path error warning
   [image]
3. In your new job you should have a build option "Python Builder"
4. Paste your code. I used this quick code:

[image]

5. Run your new job ("Build Now")

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to think of an answer to your question,

1. Add a Jenkins slave where you could configure the Python3 installation path as a tool
2. If allowed add your local machine where you have installed python3 as a Jenkins slave, that will help you to execute the script in your environment directly.
3. I hope you have added shebang line in your python script, that is the best way to instruct your script to use any specific python installation to execute the script.
4. If the Jenkins slave has the required package installed in a shared location or afs location, that can be utilized while executing the python script.